Is there a clever way to convert a compex string to multiple lists in Python 3
Here is a string :
[[15,"name",12],[2002,"another name",345]]

My actual string is much longer and stems from a text file. The structure is repetitive as indicated in the sample.
I want to convert this string to 3 different lists, namely:
int_list1 = [15, 2002]
str_list = ['name', 'another name']
int_list2 = [12, 345]

I can manage this by using the re module with re.findall() method

This doesn't look like a string: [[15,"name",12],[2002,"another name",345]]? Did you mean: "[[15,"name",12],[2002,"another name",345]]" ?

You are right you should enclose the text in single quotes when using it directly in a program. I  did read the text from a file which off course does not contains any enclosure.

Use a  list comprehensions with ast.literal_eval()
import ast

sample_string = '[[15,"name",12],[2002,"another name",345]]'
parsed_list = ast.literal_eval(sample_string)

int_list1 = [item[0] for item in parsed_list]
str_list = [item[1] for item in parsed_list]
int_list2 = [item[2] for item in parsed_list]

print("Integer List 1:", int_list1)
print("String List:", str_list)
print("Integer List 2:", int_list2)

Output
Integer List 1: [15, 2002]
String List: ['name', 'another name']
Integer List 2: [12, 345]


ast.literal_eval can turn that string into native Python lists, zip can do the regrouping:
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '[[15,"name",12],[2002,"another name",345]]'
>>> int_list1, str_list, int_list2 = zip(*literal_eval(s))
>>> int_list1
(15, 2002)
>>> str_list
('name', 'another name')
>>> int_list2
(12, 345)


I think this qualifies as "cleaver" for several reasons. First, using zip(*literal_eval(s)) to transpose our list of lists see: How to transpose a list of lists?. Secondly the use of pattern matching that result to give us three transposed lists. See: Python augmenting multiple variables inline

Chopping it up with a cleaver…
